# get the session time in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am a really new bird to python and using Django rest framework. I have followed the tutorial "http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart" and created a login logout page for admin. I wanted to track the session time or basically for how long the user has been logged in, I tried doing the same by following many tutorials like these 'https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt' but I think I'm deviating from what I want, please suggest any tutorial or any help.
Thanks

Comment: Maybe just use user.last_login

Comment: last_login will give when the user logged in but when he logged out is also needed.

Comment: Ah,  yes, missed that. So maybe just add another field for last_logout and populate it the same way as Django does for last_login? But the question is what is logout. If user clears cookies he is technically logged out,  but you cannot track this

Comment: didn't know it has last_logout too, I researched a bit but didn't find the same, can you provide some link for the same, it would be a great  help.

Comment: Use django sessions: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/sessions/.  Have a go, put some attempted code up and then let's look again

Comment: I mean,  add this field to your user model if you have a custom one. If you are using built in User model then you have more difficulties unfortunately

Comment: @AlexandrTatarinov: this will give the time of the *youngest* session. But if there are multiple, then ti will not really work.

Comment: @AlexandrTatarinov: So technically I can have last_login time and I can create some signal to notify when a logout or timeout has happened. following this "https://medium.com/@atulmishra_69567/tracking-user-login-activity-in-django-rest-framework-jwt-authentication-32e0194e77d0"

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that this is *not* stored in the `Session`s, but nothing prevents us from storing it ourselves.

We can for example construct a model `UserSession`:

```
# models.py

from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session

class UserSession(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    session = models.OneToOneField(Session, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    session_start = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Of course now we still need to ensure that such object is constructed, but we can create a *hook* for the login procedure:

```
from django.contrib.auth import user_logged_in
from django.dispatch.dispatcher import receiver

@receiver(user_logged_in)
def register_session(sender, user, request, **kwargs):

    # save current session
    request.session.save()

    # create a link from the user to the current session (for later usage)
    UserSession.objects.get_or_create(
        user=user,
        session=Session.objects.get(pk=request.session.session_key)
    )
```

We can then obtain the time the session started with:

```
from datetime import datetime

def some_view(request):
    try:
        session_started = request.session.usersession.session_start
    except UserSession.DoesNotExist:
        # ...
        # handle the case when the UserSession is not present
        pass
    else:
        session_duration = datetime.now() - session_started
        # ...
        pass
```